# How do I tell Spring Boot to ignore Jetty and always use Tomcat?

Tags: java, jetty, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, embedded-tomcat-7

I have the following setup:

```
spring-boot application (using embedded tomcat)
spring-date-neo4j (embedded mode)
spring-websockets
```

and neo4j-browser included using (the goal is to be able to use REST and web browser to debug embedded database):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And started using:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService(DatabaseConfiguration dbConf) {
    // removed with every maven clear
    return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbConf.getDbPath());

    // stays after clear
    //return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("./data/neo4j.db");
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
public WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper serverWrapper(GraphDatabaseService db) {
    WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper wrapper = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((GraphDatabaseAPI)db);
    wrapper.start();
    return wrapper;
}
```

And spring boot is insisting on trying Jetty as the servlet container even with the following config annotations for the main app class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class)
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

But the jetty version Spring uses (8) does not support web sockets so I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]:
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Websockets are currently only supported in Tomcat (found class org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory).
```

**How do I tell Spring Boot to ignore Jetty and always use Tomcat?**

The dependency tree:

```
[INFO] Building webapp 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ webapp ---
[INFO] webapp:war:1.0
[INFO] +- common:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.20:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- net.glxn:qrgen:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:pom:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:server-api:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.neo4j.3rdparty.javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.2.r612:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-commons:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-browser:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.5.v20130815:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.5.v20130815:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.5.v20130815:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:8.1.14.v20131031:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.rrd4j:rrd4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:140:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-shell:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline:jar:0.9.94_1:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:static-web:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:r239:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile (version selected from constraint [11.0,))
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile (version selected from constraint [1.3.9,))
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boot's using Jetty as it's on the classpath. The attempt to exclude it by excluding `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class` doesn't work as `EmdeddedJetty` isn't an auto-configuration class. `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` is an auto-configuration class and you could exclude it, but then you'd also lose embedded Tomcat support which I don't think is what you want. The easiest thing to do is to eliminate Jetty from your application's classpath.

The dependency tree output shows that you've still got transitive dependencies on `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server` and `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp`, both of which are being pulled in by your direct dependency on `org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server`. Update your pom to exclude them:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <classifier>static-web</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Update:** if excluding Jetty from the dependencies isn't an option, then you can declare your own `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
}
```

This will prevent the auto-configuration of the embedded Jetty server as it's conditional on there being no `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean in the application context.

Comment: Except that is exactly what I can't do, because neo4j-server starts an embedded Jetty server.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me from your question. I've updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's a life saver: I had that same problem with a conflict between activemq-http's jetty and spring-boot-starter-web :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also import the `EmbeddedTomcat` configuration directly. Has the same effect as declaring `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` directly and should there be any change with it you won't need to update anything.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat.class)
... your configuration class
```